# Why is the glog command gone for mercurial at ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial

I am using ubuntu 9.10 and installed mercurial (hg) via apt-get. If I now call

```
hg glog
```

it says: unknown command 'glog'. I am using version 1.3.1 of hg.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Mercurial 2.3 [this  - now bundled - extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GraphlogExtension) is just an alias for the `-G` switch to `hg log`.

So `hg log -G` has the same effect these days, without having to enable it in the `hgrc` file.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I had to enable it in the ~/.hgrc file:

```
[extensions]
hgext.graphlog =
```

See also
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GraphlogExtension